# Replace any of several characters with underscore

Tags: javascript

I have a simple task but I'm not sure of the syntax.

I have a string and want to replace any occurrences of '[', ']', or '.' with an underscore ('_').

I know that `string.replace()` supports regular expressions, which also give special treatment to `[` and `]`.

Comment: Escape the characters that get special treatment.

Comment: Hi just to clarify this is the square brackets and single quote is included ? or only the dot and the comma ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `replaceAll` for that

** Note, `replace` will also work since this a global search.

```
const src = '/[[\].]/g';
const target = '_';

const formated = string.replaceAll(src, target);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Comment: Why should I use `replaceAll()`? `replace()` seems to work.

Comment: `replaceAll()` replaces all occurrences of search, while `replace()` only the first occurence.

Comment: But `replace()` appears to be working and replaces all occurences.

Comment: You sure you don't have only one occurrence?

Comment: I have one of each of the three characters. So just one of each.

Comment: My bad, replace will also work since this is a global search (/g)

Answer (score 0):

Escape the characters with special treatment with backslash.

```
string = string.replace(/[[\].]/g, '_');
```

Note that `[` and `.` don't receive special treatment inside `[]`.